# creating a chart (line or bar) from php and mysql

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

i am new somehow to PHP and mysql,

I've simple database that receives the values from php form as id, date, time, max, today, tomorrow... i can insert into the table, all ok, i can also fetch the data to a php page using the below code, all ok, i can see the table of the values inserted in the db, all ok...

my need is to crate a simple line or bar chart that shows the max (which is static number each day) and the today number will be the variable that will be defined by the chart, so if it is a line it will show better that each day where is the number from the max... forget about tomorrow, it is not important...

here is my code of the display of the table of the page...

i want the simplest way to complete this, imagine only i have one column (today) that is changed each while or each day, so i want to show it in a graph against the max number... so i think the line chart will be suite best...

```
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, date, time, max, today, tomorrow, FROM testtable1");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>date</th>
<th>time</th>
<th>max</th>
<th>today</th>
<th>tomorrow</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['time'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['max'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['today'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['tomorrow'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using something like [Google Visualizations](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference) for line charts. Visualizations are easy to implement and you can write them directly on the page see their [example Line charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)

Comment: i tried actually but i couldn't, the connecting to mysql db part is not clear

Comment: anyone can help in addressing my concerns regarding the first steps to get that line chart done using google charts or any other method? please, i am using simple php and mysql db